# Recall specific from Const Table

Tags: node.js

I started my script by defining const

```
const NAME = [
    { name: "A" },
    { name: "B" },
    { name: "C" },
    { name: "D" },
    { name: "Z" }
]
```

In a special for loop, I want to go use only the first 3 const (as an example). What I should define in for()? I cannot delete the remaining const as they have other use.

Answer (score 0):

the `for loop` has a length of 3. so you would do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Comment: But how can I point var to point at const table?